# Set variable column values to nan based on row condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, slice

I want to be able to variably change a column value based on the value of the first column.

Say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
col_ind   col_1   col_2   col_3
    3       a       b       c
    2       d       e       f
    1       g       h       i
```

I effectively want to do

```
df.loc[:, df.columns[-df['col_ind']:]] = np.nan
```

Which would result in:

```
col_ind   col_1   col_2   col_3
    3      nan     nan     nan
    2       d      nan     nan
    1       g       h      nan
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets use broadcasting to check the indices which can be masked

```
c = df.columns[1:]
m = range(len(c), 0, -1) <= df['col_ind'].values[:, None]

df[c] = df[c].mask(m)
```

Result

```
   col_ind col_1 col_2 col_3
0        3   NaN   NaN   NaN
1        2     d   NaN   NaN
2        1     g     h   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `values` of `df["col_ind"]`, iterate through them and set the `slice` to `np.nan`:

```
vals = df["col_ind"].values
for i, v in enumerate(vals):
    df.iloc[i, -v:] = np.nan
```

Comment: Yeah this works but I was hoping for a more efficient solution. It's pretty time costly. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

You an use `apply` with `result_type='broadcast'`. (Edit: borrowing @marcelo-paco's code)

```
def make_nan(row):
    row[-row[0]:] = np.nan
    return row

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_ind': [3, 2, 1], 'col_1': ['a', 'd', 'g'], 'col_2': ['b', 'e', 'h'], 'col_3': ['c', 'f', 'i']})
df[:] = df.apply(make_nan, axis=1, result_type='broadcast')
df
```

This will give:

```
col_ind col_1   col_2   col_3
    3   NaN      NaN    NaN
    2   d        NaN    NaN
    1   g         h     NaN
```

Comment: Is `row[-row[0]:]' pseudo code? Do you not need to specify iloc?

Comment: It's not a pseudo code. It is using the first element to index the rest of the elements.

Comment: This method crashes the kernal of my notebook. Also in my code I want to use a named column, I've replaced 0 with 'col name', I assume that is fine?

Comment: This assumes the values in col_ind are between 1 and 3. Not sure what you mean by "replaced 0 with 'col name'. You can make an edit and update your question.

Comment: I used a mock df for my example but my actual df is larger, so instead of using the column index for the condition column, I used the column name. Presumably the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could create new columns with slices of the current columns and then replace

```py
for i, cn in enumerate(df.columns,1): 
    df[cn] = [*[np.nan]*i, *df[cn].loc[i:]]
```

> [image: op]